# CQRS/EventStore: How are failures to deliver events handled?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Getting into CQRS and I understand that you have commands (app layer) and events (from the domain).

In the simple case where events are to update the read model, do read model updates fail? If there is no "bug" then I cannot see them failing and as I am using EventStore, I know there is a commit flag which will retry failures.

So my question is do I have to do anything in addition to EventStore to handle failures?

Coming from a world where you do everything in one transaction and now things are done separately is worrying me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there may be cases where a published event will fail in the read models.

You have to make sure you can detect that and solve it.

The nice thing is that you can replay all the events again and again so you have the chance not only to fix the error. You can also test the fix by replaying every single event if you want.

I use NServiceBus as my publishing mechanism which allows me to use an error queue. Using my other logging tools together with the error queue I can easily determine what happened since I have the error log and the actual message that caused the error in the first place.

Comment: My read model and my event store are on the same machine. Would it be an overkill to use NServiceBus or should I be planning for it now?  Also, unless there is some sort of bug in the app, what could cause the events fail in the read model? Can you tell me more about your error queue and the work involved to get it implemented (considering I have zero experience in NServiceBus).

Comment: When using NServiceBus (and MSMQ as transport) is that the messages are persisted. This means that if you get an exception for whatever reason, you can have a look at the actual message as it was sent. Plus you can drop it into the input queue again and rerun it. Also, NServiceBus provides a really simple way to setup Sending and Publishing of messages. It's not that tricky to get started either. Have a look at the samples and have a go at it.

Comment: @Mikael Östberg, +1.   I thought Nservicebus/event queue was used for communication between microservices/endpoints.  Do you use them inside a microservice/endpoint?

Comment: You can use it between machines or processes, but also within the same process. What it brings is a queuing mechanism that gives you means of durability and throttling. I recently built something where distributed transactions were impossible and in that case I used the bus to send commands within the process. Perform one task (within an implicit atomic transaction) and the send a command to the next step. That pattern may not the prettiest or the simplest, but it would give durability as you allow for each step to fail with the possibility to recover from the failed state.